# Handling dead letter queue with delay

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, dead-letter

I want to do the following: when a message fails and falls to my dead letter queue, I want to wait 5 minutes and republishes the same message on my queue.

Today, using Spring Cloud Streams and RabbitMQ, I did the following code [Based on this documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/2.1.0.RC3/single/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_non_partitioned_destinations):

```java
@Component
public class HandlerDlq {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HandlerDlq.class);
    private static final String X_RETRIES_HEADER = "x-retries";
    private static final String X_DELAY_HEADER = "x-delay";
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_RETRIES = 3;
    private static final int DELAY_MS = 300000;
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public HandlerDlq(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = MessageInputProcessor.DLQ)
    public void rePublish(Message failedMessage) {
        Map<String, Object> headers = failedMessage.getMessageProperties().getHeaders();
        Integer  retriesHeader = (Integer) headers.get(X_RETRIES_HEADER);
        if (retriesHeader == null) {
            retriesHeader = 0;
        }
        if (retriesHeader > NUMBER_OF_RETRIES) {
            LOGGER.warn("Message {} added to failed messages queue", failedMessage);
            this.rabbitTemplate.send(MessageInputProcessor.FAILED, failedMessage);
            throw new ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException("Message failed after " + NUMBER_OF_RETRIES + " attempts");
        }
        retriesHeader++;
        headers.put(X_RETRIES_HEADER, retriesHeader);
        headers.put(X_DELAY_HEADER, DELAY_MS * retriesHeader);
        LOGGER.warn("Retrying message, {} attempts", retriesHeader);
        this.rabbitTemplate.send(MessageInputProcessor.DELAY_EXCHANGE, MessageInputProcessor.INPUT_DESTINATION, failedMessage);
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange delayExchange() {
        DirectExchange exchange = new DirectExchange(MessageInputProcessor.DELAY_EXCHANGE);
        exchange.setDelayed(true);
        return exchange;
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindOriginalToDelay() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(new Queue(MessageInputProcessor.INPUT_DESTINATION)).to(delayExchange()).with(MessageInputProcessor.INPUT_DESTINATION);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue parkingLot() {
        return new Queue(MessageInputProcessor.FAILED);
    }
}
```

My `MessageInputProcessor` interface:

```java
public interface MessageInputProcessor {

    String INPUT = "myInput";

    String INPUT_DESTINATION = "myInput.group";

    String DLQ = INPUT_DESTINATION + ".dlq"; //from application.properties file

    String FAILED = INPUT + "-failed";

    String DELAY_EXCHANGE = INPUT_DESTINATION + "-DlqReRouter";

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel storageManagerInput();

    @Input(MessageInputProcessor.FAILED)
    SubscribableChannel storageManagerFailed();
}
```

And my properties file:

```
#dlx/dlq setup - retry dead letter 5 minutes later (300000ms later)
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.myInput.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.myInput.consumer.republish-to-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.myInput.consumer.dlq-ttl=3000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.myInput.consumer.delayedExchange=true


#input
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myInput.destination=myInput
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myInput.group=group
```

With this code, I can read from dead letter queue, capture the header but I can't put it back to my queue (the line `LOGGER.warn("Retrying message, {} attempts", retriesHeader);` only runs once, even if I put a very slow time).

My guess is that the method `bindOriginalToDelay` is binding the exchange to a new queue, and not mine. However, I didn't find a way to get my queue to bind there instead of creating a new one. But I'm not even sure this is the error.

I've also tried to send to  `MessageInputProcessor.INPUT` instead of `MessageInputProcessor.INPUT_DESTINATION`, but it didn't work as expected.

Also, unfortunately, I can't update Spring framework due to dependencies on the project...

Could you help me with putting back the failed message on my queue after some time? I really didn't want to put a `thread.sleep` there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that configuration, `myInput.group` is bound to the delayed (topic) exchange `myInput` with routing key `#`.

You should probably remove `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.myInput.consumer.delayedExchange=true` because you don't need the main exchange to be delayed.

It will also be bound to your explicit delayed exchange, with key `myInput.group`.

Everything looks correct to me; you should see the same (single) queue bound to two exchanges:

[image]

The `myInput.group.dlq` is bound to `DLX` with key `myInput.group`

You should set a longer TTL and examine the message in the DLQ to see if something stands out.

**EDIT**

I just copied your code with a 5 second delay and it worked fine for me (with turning off the delay on the main exchange).

```
Retrying message, 4 attempts
```

and

```
added to failed messages queue
```

Perhaps you thought it was not working because you have a delay on the main exchange too?

Comment: I just tested your code with a 5 second delay and no delay on the `myInput` exchange and it all works fine; perhaps you were being misled because of the additional delay on the main exchange?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've checked the bindings, just like the image you posted, and in my code it is not binded to `DlqReRouter` one. In fact, it doesn't even appear in the exchange list. I wonder if it is happening because the queue already existed before I ran, or maybe I'm mixing things up with the names somewhere...

Comment: Yes; you can't change a queue once it has been created; you have to delete it to create it with new arguments.